# Way to expand a Word autocorrect shortcut without typing a space or puntuation

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I sometimes want insert and expand an autocorrect shortcut leaving the cursor after it and without adding any of the usual triggers, ie a space or punctuation.
If there isn't a built in way, I'll just create a macro that inserts and deletes a space, but that seems rather crude watching all the text jump around.

Answer (score 1):

### There is no way to do this within the AutoCorrect function.

It requires the termination of the trigger key (space or punctuation).

You could, instead, use AutoText and insert it using the F3 key.